# SAS: in the DATA step, how to calculate the grand mean of a subset of observations, skipping over missing values

Tags: sas, mean, missing-data

I'm trying to calculate the grand mean of a subset of observations (e.g., observation 20 to observation 50) in the `data` step.  In this calculation, I also want to skip over (ignore) any missing values.

I've tried to play around with the `mean` function using various `if … then` statements, but I can't seem to fit all of it together.

Any help would be much appreciated.

For reference, here's the basic outline of my data steps:

```
data sas1;
 infile '[file path]';
 input v1 $ 1-9 v2 $ 11 v3 13-17 [redacted] RPQ 50-53 [redacted] v23 101-106;
    v1=translate(v1,"0"," ");
 format [redacted];
 label [redacted];
run;

data gmean;
 set sas1;
 id=_N_;
 if id = 10-40 then do;
   avg = mean(RPQ);
   end;
 /*Here, I am trying to calculate the grand mean of the RPQ variable*/
 /*but only observations 10 to 40, and skipping over missing values*/
run;
```

Comment: If you're doing it via a data step its best to show your code as there are a variety of methods. In general, I would recommend proc means as it ignores missing values by default.

Comment: @Reeza Thanks for your comment. I've added my abbreviated code above for reference. Typically I would also use `proc means`, but in this case I'm limited to the `data` step.

Comment: Your code doesn't show what you've tried. Are you expecting the result to be in all rows (10-40) or just the final row?

Comment: @Reeza  Oh, sorry.  Everything I tried was pretty unintelligible, but I'll add some lines in a sec.

Comment: @Reeza Just the final row, i.e., the single mean of all the observations (10 to 40).  Also, I just added some lines that are representative of how I was trying to approach the calculation.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the automatic variable /*_N_*/ to id the rows. Use a sum value that is retained row to row and then divide by the number of observations at the end. Use the missing() function to determine the number of observations present and whether or not to add to the running total.

```
data stocks;
set sashelp.stocks;
retain sum_total n_count 0;
if 10<=_n_<=40 and not missing(open) then do;
    n_count=n_count+1;
    sum_total=sum_total+open;
end;

if _n_ = 40 then average=sum_total/n_count;
run;

proc print data=stocks(obs=40 firstobs=40);
var average;
run;

*check with proc means that the value is correct;
proc means data=sashelp.stocks (firstobs=10 obs=40) mean;
var open;
run;
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. :)  I'm headed to a different computer, and so in a bit I'll let you know if this worked for me.  Thank you very much.

Comment: It took a bit of tweaking with my own dataset, but this ended up working (and I corroborated it with `proc means` and Excel). Thanks again for taking the time to help me.